# android app crashes while trying to run in

Tags: android

hello there am trying to run a an android app which i made from android studio to my moto g mobile phone ... bt it keep telling as unfortunately ,"Expence has stopped"  ... it point to my android maifest file pls help me

this is main activity

```
package com.example.vikki.expense;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText salary ;
    EditText net;
    EditText petrol;
    EditText cw;
    EditText food;
    EditText expence;
    Button next;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //find the value by id
        salary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        net = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        petrol = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        cw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        food = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


        next.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);



    }
     public void onClick(View v ) {

         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         float num1 = 0;
         float num2 = 0;
         float num3 = 0;
         float num4 = 0;
         float num5 = 0;
         float result = 0;




         // read EditText and fill variables with numbers
         num1 = Float.parseFloat(salary.getText().toString());
         num2 = Float.parseFloat(net.getText().toString());
         num3 = Float.parseFloat(petrol.getText().toString());
         num4 = Float.parseFloat(cw.getText().toString());
         num5 = Float.parseFloat(food.getText().toString());

         result = num1+num2+num3+num4+num5;

         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);
         startActivity(intent);









     }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vikki.expense"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.vikki.expense.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.vikki.expense.Activity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_activity2" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

this is xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/Expense"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/ex1"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/ex2"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="@string/ex3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/ex4"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/ex5"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please use the logcat window to see the full stacktrace for the error in your application. This will point you to the exact location of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

MainActivity should implements `View.OnClickListener` if you are using `next.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: Thank u ... now its working with out any crash but when i click the button it is supposed to go the next activity it giving the same error

Comment: @srivignesh I just cannot guess what caused the crash when your click the button to open the next activity without your code or the log of crash. Using logcat to find the detail of exception, and then you can fix it yourself or just ask here again.

Answer (score 0):

I found it funny, to debug this probram without a crash...

I think that the problem is with layout.

Staring with id **editText2** in your layout you are using *TextView*-s and casting them to *EditText* in the code.  IMHO it won't work.
Either use TextView in the code or change TextView to EditText in the layout file when needed